# Get the ID's of all the elements in the array

Tags: javascript

I want to get all the elements that are having an ID and want to store that id value in an array and I am using the following method:

```
var allTheElementsHavingID = document.querySelectorAll('[id]');
var allTheID = [];
for(i=0;i<allTheElementsHavingID.length;i++)
{
  allTheID.push(allTheElementsHavingID[i].id);
}
```

But the problem here is that I am having around 15000 elements with an ID.
and when I run the code in console it freezes the browser.
so I want the alternative of the for loop here so as to store all the ID's
**Is there any other method??** that will prove more efficient

Comment: Why, exactly, would you want to store all of the IDs in an array?

Comment: @RaxWeber I am checking that the id provided in anchor tag's destination(href) exists or not.

Comment: @RaxWeber If you know a method of doing so please suggest that. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just do `if (document.getElementById(idFromHash))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. it will change the loop to perform asynchronously so it can take as long as it needs to process the elements and will not crash the browser.

```js
const els = document.querySelectorAll('[id]')

function asyncLoop(els, callback) {
  let ii = 0
  const ret = []
  const length = els.length
  
  function iter() {
    const id = els[ii].id
    const link = document.querySelector(`a[href*=${id}]`)
    if (!link) {
      ret.push(els[ii].id)
    }
    if (++ii < length) {
      return setTimeout(iter, 0)
    }
    callback(ret)
  }
  iter()
}

asyncLoop(els, function(missingIds){
  console.log(missingIds)
})
```

```html
<a id="one" href="#one">one</a>
<a id="two" href="#two">two</a>
<a id="fail" href="#three">three</a>
```

I'm not sure that getting and iterating a list with 15,000 elements is a good idea. You could evaluate the `'hashchange'` to see if there is a matching element when the link is clicked. It would give you the chance to handle any errors.

returning `!!element` will prevent the action if there is no matching element

```js
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function(e) {
  var element = document.querySelector(location.hash)
  console.log(element)
  return !!element
})
```

```html
<a id="one" href="#one">one</a>
<a id="two" href="#two">two</a>
<a id="fail" href="#three">three</a>
```

Comment: Thanks the solution is good, Is there a way by which I  can know if there is matching element without clicking the link???

Comment: Not with this solution. why do you have such a large list and so many id's on the page? and are there less links with hrefs than id's?

Comment: the requirement is to publish a book in html format and the book's page no. are 1237 each page consist of something that has to be linked.

Comment: I think there is some confusion,

Comment: So this is a one time script in your compilation for a static asset that can be distributed, or you need to do this each time a webpage is open?

Comment: Yes synthet1c its one time script compilation at my end only, not everytime when webpage is open. But I have other books also which are having same number of links therefore I turned to develop a common solution.

Comment: @KaranParikh edited the answer. That script will not care how many elements you give it or how long it takes, and it shouldn't prevent you from interacting with the page.

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that looping over so many items is always going to take some time. But maybe using a built-in function like `.map()` will be faster than your own loop.

```
var allTheID = [].map.call(allTheElementsHavingID, e => e.id);
```

But apparently I'm wrong.

[JQuery map vs Javascript map vs For-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551139/jquery-map-vs-javascript-map-vs-for-loop)

Comment: I thought native loops were faster than the Array methods.

Comment: You're right, I found some other questions that address that.

Comment: I think you should still use the Array methods as they are easier to understand and it gives the browser vendors the ability to optimize their code behind the scenes. 15,000 iterations is a fair bit though.

Comment: For small arrays that's probably right. But if the loop is a performance bottleneck, using a slower method will just make things even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Try [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const allTheElementsHavingID = document.querySelectorAll('[id]');
const allTheID = [...allTheElementsHavingID].map(element => element.id);
console.log(allTheID);
```

```html
<div id="one">a</div>
<div id="two">b</div>
<div id="three">c</div>
<div id="four">d</div>
<div id="five">e</div>
```

If you are using TypeScript and face this error:

> Type 'IterableIterator' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.

Instead of

```js
[...allTheElementsHavingID].map(element => element.id)]
```

you can rely on [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
Array.from(allTheElementsHavingID, element => element.id)
```

More on [`downlevelIteration`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69046124/1248177)

Answer (score -1):

You could give them all the elements same class, then get the IDs of all the elements with the same class. Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qdk9d55w/4/

```
 var elementIds = [];
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
 for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (elements[i].id != '') {
        elementIds.push(elements[i].id);
    }
 }
 alert(elementIds);
```

Comment: No Alex they are not same.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qdk9d55w/ just give all of those elements the same class, regardless if the elements are different.

Comment: Thank you Alex but even if I add class name to all the elements the problem still exists because document.getElementsByClassName will return the elements with same class name not their "IDs"

Comment: Did you look at the js fiddle that I made? That is not true. I updated it.

Comment: I'm doing exactly what you are asking with this, grabbing all the elements you need, getting their ids, and putting them into an array.

Comment: I appreciate your time and efforts but, Alex the main concern was I don't want to insert the id's of the elements into the array through the iterations of for loop because the number of id's span upto 15000

Comment: Oh, that makes sense then. I thought it was 15,000 elements on the entire page, not the amount of elements you needed. The question was confusing, getting that much data shouldn't be done the way you intend, just my opinion.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you and yeah your opinion is correct this is not the method that I should use. Open for suggestions