# Get the div of an array from an HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I would like to return only the id of each div and keep them in an array :

```js
const projects = [...document.getElementsByClassName("nav-project")];
console.log(projects);
      
//expected output : [one, two, three, four, five]
```

```html
<div class="nav-project" id="one">a</div>
<div class="nav-project" id="two">b</div>
<div class="nav-project" id="three">c</div>
<div class="nav-project" id="four">d</div>
<div class="nav-project" id="five">e</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the ID's of all the elements in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060497/get-the-ids-of-all-the-elements-in-the-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const projects = [...document.getElementsByClassName("nav-project")]
  .map(div => div.id);

  console.log(projects);
```

```html
<div class="nav-project" id="one">a</div>
<div class="nav-project" id="two">b</div>
<div class="nav-project" id="three">c</div>
<div class="nav-project" id="four">d</div>
<div class="nav-project" id="five">e</div>
```

Comment: Be even better if you could find the obvious duplicate instead of answering...

Comment: @HereticMonkey well the amount of items in the other question made it a bit different though

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Array.from()` to convert a NodeList to an array of ids:

```js
const projects = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('.nav-project'),
  el => el.id
)

console.log(projects)
```

```html
<div class="nav-project" id="one">a</div>
<div class="nav-project" id="two">b</div>
<div class="nav-project" id="three">c</div>
<div class="nav-project" id="four">d</div>
<div class="nav-project" id="five">e</div>
```

Comment: This answer is really good because it has the additional benefit of avoiding [downleveling error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69046124/1248177)