# Copying an array produces strange results ('copying'==referencing)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

EDIT: the problem I came across was that I did not know that js arrays are treated as objects and any as so are referenced not copied. If you were interested in simply reversing a js array you can use...reverse();

I thought I would be able to simply do the following in javascript

```
var originalArray = [1,2,3,5,8,13];
var originalArrayCOPY = originalArray;
console.log ("new copy = "+originalArrayCOPY);

for(var zyx = 0; zyx <6; zyx++){
    var xyz = 5-zyx;
    originalArray[zyx] = originalArrayCOPY[xyz];
}

console.log("original now "+originalArray);
console.log("copy ="+originalArrayCOPY);
```

But my results are so strange that I feel I must not understand javascript at all!!

new copy = 1,2,3,5,8,13

original now 13,8,5,5,8,13,

copy =13,8,5,5,8,13,

I can-t see why this wouldn-t work and I honestly am not sure why the COPY of the original array is changed at all.

If I could at least name the problem I could ask google, also if you tell me the name of the problem I will rename by SO question.

Comment: don't use such variables names...it confuses most of the people.

Comment: Cannot disagree with your comment about your understanding of Javascript. You can call it a copy, but it's not, it's the exact same array. If you want a real copy, try `originalArray.slice()`.

Comment: Obviously the two arrays "contain" the same data. So the assignment performed a shallow copy when you wanted a deep copy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy

Comment: @torazaburo, i can see that-s what happened, in a programming language what would that be called where you can or can-t straight copy an array? is it the same for variables?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's not even a shallow copy. It's just two references to the same object.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: yep, one reference was copied to the other.

Comment: But for example PHP and js differ here, how can I check which way a language works with var = var?

Comment: Your question seems to be similar to either  [Copying array by value in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript) or [Most efficient way to reverse an array in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276953/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-reverse-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
var originalArray = [1,2,3,5,8,13];
var originalArrayCOPY = originalArray.slice();
console.log ("new copy = "+originalArrayCOPY);
for(var zyx = 0; zyx <6; zyx++){
    var xyz = 5-zyx;
    originalArray[zyx] = originalArrayCOPY[xyz];
}

console.log("original now "+originalArray);
console.log("copy ="+originalArrayCOPY);
```

'=' copy references and slice() will produce a new copy of the array.
see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Cool. Thanks. One question about referencing if I may? if array[keyN] is also an array, does newArray = array[keyN] make a copy or a reference to array[keyN]?

Comment: to answer my own question, it is still a reference not a copy.

Comment: the actual initial problem could also simply be solved with array.reverse()