# Order a array in descendent order in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to know if exits some incorporated method in Javascript that turn from back to front a array or I have to create it

example

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
```

to

```
var fruits = ["Mango","Apple","Orange","Banana"];
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276953/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-reverse-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: The title of your question does not match the content. Do you want to impose an ordering based on the values in the array, or do you simply want to reverse the existing order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use the [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.reverse();
```

Please have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zmduzuet/).

Comment: Why was this downvoted, I wonder? It doesn't match the *title* but it does match the content of the post.

Comment: Restored justice on both

Comment: @Pointy thank you very much for your comment. At least someone had the same question like me.

Comment: Thanks Christos. I get confused. I thought that reverse order the array in descendent order and alphabetical