# (JS) make for-loop function go from last to first

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This code is now making `1` to `4`. How can it make `4` to `1` (last to first)?

```
var nb = 4;
var first = ' active';
if (nb > 1) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= nb; i++) {
        page  = page+'<span class="to-step-nb'+first+'">'+0+String(i)+'</span>';
        first = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing a `}` btw.

Comment: There are a thousand ways to loop backwards, and I'm sure you could have googled it a lot faster than the time it took to write the question, but here you go, my favorite backwards loop: `for(var i=len;i-->1;) { .. }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to reverse an array in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276953/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-reverse-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `nb` should be `number` not `string`
2. You're missing `}` at the end
3. Use the condition

   ```
   for (var i = nb; i > 0; i--)
   ```

   to reverse the loop.
4. `String(i)` is not required
5. `first` is set to empty string, after first iteration, so now, you'll have last item active
6. `if (nb > 1)`, is not required, as if the condition fails, `for` will not execute
7. You can use Shorthand for `a = a + ..` as `a += ..`

Code:

```
var nb = 4;
var first = ' active';

for (var i = nb; i > 0; i--) {
    page += '<span class="to-step-nb' + first + '">' + 0 + i + '</span>';
    first = '';
}
```

Comment: Question.. Now it thinks 4 is first and adds +first+ to the class, How can I make 1 first so 1 will get +first+ class?

Comment: Use if statement in loop to check and add

Comment: Would you please show me like I have no JS knowledge (because I don't!)

Comment: I tried `for (var i = nb; i > 0; i--) { if (i = 1) { first = ''; } }` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = nb; i >= 1; i--) {
  // do something
}
```