# How can I filter or sort latest post in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am trying to render post in different views like for the latest post i want it to  view with title and image and for other just title and excerpt. I am not sure how to do that one way i found out is by slicing loop something like this.

```
import React from 'react'
import PostPreview from './PostPreview/PostPreview';

export default function RenderPost(props) {
  return (
    <div>
        {props.posts && props.posts.edges.slice(0, 1).map(post => (
            <PostPreview
                id={post.node.id}
                key={post.node.id}
                title={post.node.title}
                imageUrl= {post.node.featuredImage.sourceUrl}
            />
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am getting data from wordpress/graphql.

But i am not sure this is the right way or not. In this way i think i will need to pass posts data from single parent element to two different component I guess. is there any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You just use props.posts.reverse() before map function.

Refer following link.
 [React: Given an array, render the elements in reverse order efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664041/react-given-an-array-render-the-elements-in-reverse-order-efficiently)

Comment: that not what i want.  I want to find a way to separate the latest post with rest of the post.